# Identify hidden control character and ignore when scanning csv file

Tags: matlab, csv, character, textscan

I am trying to use `textscan` in MATLAB to read in mixed format data from a .csv file. I am currently running into a problem that there are a number of nonvisible characters which are getting read in as a string when I am not expecting them. I believe if I set this character as a delimiter or whitespace it will solve my text scanning issue.

My main problem at the moment is that I don't know what character it is to be able to identify it. I have used `isstrprop` to determine that it is a control character. I guessed that it was the `NUL` character, so I tried adding `\0` to the delimiter set for `textscan`. Unfortunately MATLAB does not recognize that as a valid `\` constant.

Below is one line of the data file, copied from Notepad. The characters preceding each of the commas are the ones in question. The following line is the command I used in MATLAB to read it.

```
1     ,T,171215,173201,21.982413N,159.342881W,150  ,0   ,0  ,3D,SPS ,2.7  ,2.5  ,1.0  ,         

C = textscan(fid,'%d%s%d%d%s%s%d%d%d%s%s%f%f%f%s','delimiter',',','headerlines',1,'MultipleDelimsAsOne',1)
```

Also, for what it's worth, using `deblank` on the string of characters that is read in does remove them. However, I only know how to apply this *after* the `textscan`, so the characters still throw off the parsing.

How can I identify this character and set it to be ignored by `textscan`?

Comment: Can you isolate a line that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @excaza Yes, I suppose that would be helpful. Question updated.

Comment: I directly used `C = textscan(fid,'%d%s%d%d%s%s%d%d%d%s%s%f%f%f%s','delimiter',',')` for a file with only the line you mentioned (saved as .txt) and it worked perfectly fine for me in R2014a in ubuntu 16.04 (returned a 1x15 cell with all the data types and values well separated) 
Are you sure the error is in this line only and not in the previous one ?

Comment: @SaurabhSaini I would assume that the problem character got converted into whitespace somewhere between when I copied it from the file and pasted it here and when you copied it from here and pasted it in a text file. And yes, I'm sure, because I can read in the first `1` value, but the next term is then the 5 character "whitespace", not a `T` as it should be.

Comment: You have the csv file. Why can't you just use a binary dump or editor to find out what's in it?

Comment: @EML Because I don't know how to do a binary dump, and every editor I have displays the characters as either whitespace or hidden (it takes 5 arrow clicks to move one visible character). If you could explain how to do either of these that would be helpful. Also, simply identifying the character is not useful unless I also know how to represent that in MATLAB.